# Ubuntu Mate presents three(!!!) lock screens after suspend / reopening the lid

Tags: lock-screen, ubuntu-mate

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 and I am using the Mate desktop.
On my Razer Blade laptop, when I close the without logging off, then open the lid again, I have to enter my password three times to get back in.

The first unlock screen seems to come from the gnome screensaver, the second and third from mate screensaver. I tried simply killing mate screensaver as an experiment but after waking up from suspend, I get all three lock screens again and mate-screensaver has been restarted somehow.

When I kill gnome-screensaver instead, closing the lid will not suspend my computer any more nor will the screen get locked after a certain timeout.

So there appears to be no simple way to make it work as it should. 
Is there a way to fix what obviously has got to be an annoying bug?

Is there a bug report about this somewhere, this really should get fixed.

I would probably prefer to have everything handled by gnome-screensaver: not only does it look better, I also use the Ubuntu desktop every now and then and would still want screen locking  to work there.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu 18.04 or Ubuntu-MATE 18.04.  If it was the former as your text states, you could have both gnome-screensaver & mate-screensaver active & asking for unlock (*screensavers also handle locking* https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gnome-screensaver).  The third maybe xscreensaver.  Have you loaded multiple DEsktops? or you mean you have a fresh install of Ubuntu-Mate 18.04?

Comment: Thanks - I have updated my post. The second and third password prompts look identical and seem to both come from the mate screensaver (but only one is running). I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, not updated from an older version, after which I also installed the Mate desktop, gnome desktop and cinnamon desktop (to figure out which of them is least crap with very high screen resolutions)

Comment: If you enter ` ps -elf |grep screen` you may notice multiple in memory & running. I'd suggest `kill`ing all but the one related to your current running DEsktop, and see if that fixes it.  The testing of Ubuntu-Mate assumes it only is there, Ubuntu assumes only gnome is there etc, and your case isn't tested (because of resources).  If you want to create a bug report on launchpad (https://launchpad.net; *but `ubuntu-bug` is easier*), I'll look at it :)  *even try and help if I can*

Comment: You mentioned fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, .. "also installed ... gnome-desktop .." which strikes me as strange. Ubuntu 18.04 contains the gnome-desktop!  I'd also check what you actually installed as something doesn't add up.

Comment: Edited again: i see only one each of the mate and gnome screensaver processes running, but killing the mate one does not help since it will get restarted somehow an the original problem persists, and killing the gnome one does not help since then it breaks major required functionality, apparently

Comment: "*breaks major required .. apparently?*"  - I don't understand, if I `killall /usr/bin/mate-screensaver ; `killall /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver ; killall xscreensaver` the effect is they are no longer running (i think xfce causes xscreensaver to run on my box, but no other effects)  Kill only effects running processes, useful to see if they help. If you re-login they'll return to normal...

Comment: @guiverc as I wrote in my edited main post, if I kill the gnome screensaver it breaks what I need: locking the screen after a timeout or when closing the lid. If I kill the mate screensaver, it does not help because it somehow gets restarted automatically and I get multiple password prompts again.