# Second blue lock screen showing after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, lock-screen, mate

I use Mate as my desktop environment and I recently upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04.

Since the upgrade, I now have two lock screens. If I lock my screen (Ctrl-Alt-L), I get the expected Mate screensaver, but sometimes when I unlock it I get an additional light blue lock screen, just containing a password field.

I end up having to unlock both to get back to my desktop. The last time this happened, the blue screen didn't show a password field and I had to reboot my machine.

I think the blue lock screen is being fired from a timer, somewhere. If I leave my computer locked for long enough, the blue screen will be waiting for me. However if I briefly lock and unlock my machine, only the Mate screensaver appears.

Any ideas what this is? After researching some similar issues, I tried removing `gnome-screensaver`, but it hasn't fixed anything.

[This question is related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038283/ubuntu-mate-presents-three-lock-screens-after-suspend-reopening-the-lid), however I upgraded rather than a fresh install. Also I have two lock screens, not three, and I've already removed gnome-screensaver.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Everything points to `gnome-screensaver` being the culprit. Have you rebooted _after_ uninstalling it?

Comment: @MrShunz Yup, that was the problem :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comments, `gnome-screensaver` is interfering and should be uninstalled.

After uninstalling, you should reboot your system as the screensaver is still running in memory.

*Probably* a logout is enough, but I'm not sure if `gnome-screensaver` gets killed on logout, so a reboot is safer.